# Using Pundit for Rails 5 Authorization with two different user tables (User and Admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

If using Pundit for authorization in a Blog app, Devise for Authentication with different user tables for User and Admin, how can a Policy for Posts be implemented where:

- Users can update their own posts
- Admins can update anyone's post

In the examples I've seen online, there does not seem to be a provision for handling multiple user tables such as Admin and User.

Having a UserPolicy and AdminPolicy that are specific to their respective tables is straightforward, but how does the PostPolicy implement a  feature something like:

```
def initialize(COULD BE A USER OR ADMIN, scope)
  @user = USER OR ADMIN
  @scope = scope
end

def update?
  return true if user is either resource.user or ANY ADMIN
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are in different tables, I assume User and Admin are also in different classes, you can just use `is_a?` to check.

```
def update?
  @user == resource.user || @user.is_a?(Admin)
end
```